# Why using Local<Value>::New together with String::New()

Tags: node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I used this:

```
 Local<Value> argv[argc] = { String::New("hello world") };
```

But now I see the example on node.js website:

```
 Local<Value> argv[argc] = { Local<Value>::New(String::New("hello world")) };
```

What does it mean? What's difference, when an dwhy I should use `Local<Value>` in addition to `String::New()`

Comment: Is your usage in the context of calling a callback?

Comment: @Joe, I have simpler functions and those that call callbacks

Comment: The only code I've seen in the node addon docs use that construct in the context of a native addon calling a JS callback.  But I wish I knew if it "mattered".

Comment: What's particularly interesting is that the "unstable" ver (0.11.x) docs have changed to not do this... e.g. http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.11.11/docs/api/addons.html#addons_callbacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the node.js example in this case was wrong/inefficient.

https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/98aad77f466d9c36947f2cbb6d07b75009795ed2#commitcomment-5532648

> jnardone added a note 2 hours ago
>
> Was this just one of those things that was always wrong, or was there
>   an underlying v8 change that meant that this should change? The
>   additional Local::New always looked odd but I can't tell if something
>   buried inside v8 required this additional wrapper or not.
>
> bnoordhuis added a note 7 minutes ago
>
> It's cleanup. Creating a Local out of a Local is not
>   actively harmful but it's superfluous and slightly inefficient.

So, your first format is fine.